# How to use multiple cell.textLabel.text for multiple tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create two `tableviews` into one single `UIViewController`, Here I have created two `tableview` with `If conditional statement` to operate separate process for separate tables. But the problem is I need to create `separate cell.textLabel.text` for separate `tables`. Whenever I clicked the cell I am getting first `Tableview cell.textLabel.text` value.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableView==tableone)
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.text = [....]; // Here I am applying first table values 
    }
    if (tableView==tabletwo) {

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.text = [....]; // here I am applying my values 
    }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

   if (tableView==tableone) {

      UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
       NSLog(@"%@",cellText);
   }

  if (tableView==tabletwo) {

      UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
       NSLog(@"%@",cellText);
   }

}
```

Comment: put a breakpoint inside the second if statement in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and tell me if the breakpoint gets hit

Comment: Yes It comming!@saheb Roy

Comment: can u plz show me the condition where you are switching between the two tableviews?

Comment: I have mentioned above if (tableView==tableone) for tableview one and two aso same! but whloe I am clicking cell.textLabel. from table two I can get table one value. I need to get table two value

Comment: Perhaps you can show us how `tableone` and `tabletwo` were set. I suspect a problem in one or both of those variables. Examine them and compare them to the actual table views and see if they match up properly. Unrelated, but you really shouldn't be going to the cell to retrieve the text. This is MVC, so you should be looking it up in the model, not the view. Also, I'd be inclined to have separate delegate objects for each table view to avoid needing to have these `if` statements in each delegate method.

Comment: i think, you should use isEqual for checking the tableone & tabletwo rather than ==. (eg . [tableView isEqual:tableone]).

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can give tag of the tableview in utility view.
    after giving tag you can use tableview using given particular tag.

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableView.tag == 1)
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.text = [....]; 
    }
    if (tableView.tag ==2) {

        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.text = [....];
    }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

   if (tableView.tag == 1) {

      UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
       NSLog(@"%@",cellText);
   }

  if (tableView.tag == 2) {

      UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
       cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
       NSLog(@"%@",cellText);
   }
}
```

// I think this will help you..

Comment: what the difference between your answer and question both are same , in your answer identify with tags and question identify with tableName, please change your answer